# Odds of a large sample size, given a binary choice, EXACTLY splitting their answers down the middle?

Tags: probability

Sorry in advance, because I know very little about statistics... Say I have a large sample size (n=500 for example), and I offer a choice that has two options (or, I guess to put it simply, I ask them a yes or no question).

How do I find the odds that the responses will be split exactly down the middle (so n/2 answers yes and n/2 answers no), assuming that each individual has a 50/50 chance of voting one way or the other?

In other words...

n = large number divisible by 2

odds of choosing either option = .5 for each individual (random)

What are the odds of...

exactly n/2 chooses one of two options

exactly n/2 chooses the other option

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\Pr(X=250|n=500, p=0.5) = 0.03566464555$. For other n and p, you can use this online binomial calculator. https://stattrek.com/online-calculator/binomial.aspx

Answer (score 1):

To make the mathematics a bit simpler, let's set $2m=n$. We seek the probability is that of getting $m=$ heads in $2m$ tosses of a fair coin.

Now $P(X=m) = {2m \choose m} \frac12^{2m}$  from the binomial distribution. This is the exact probability under independent trials with constant $p=\frac12$.

For large $m$ this is approximately $\sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi m}}$, or $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi n}}$ (via Stirling's approximation).

Calculating in R, for 500 tosses the chance of 250 heads is:

```
> dbinom(250,500,.5)
[1] 0.03566465
```

or by direct computation

```
> choose(500,250)/2^500
[1] 0.03566465
```

by the approximation:

```
> 1/sqrt(250*pi)
[1] 0.03568248
```

You can see that the approximation gives several figures of accuracy for n this large. A quick in-head approximation is $0.8/\sqrt{n}$. e.g. if $n=10000$, it gives 0.008 while the correct value is 0.00798

More accurate approximations are possible, but the $\propto n^{-\frac12}$ version is often sufficient for many purposes